# How to disable button when stage shows

Tags: javafx

Hello I want to disabled a button when a stage shows, I named the Button `registros` and i named the stage `registrosiniciales` this is the code when i open the stage.

```
public void mostrarregistrosi() throws IOException {

        Stage registrosiniciales=new Stage();
        FXMLLoader cargaregistros = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("TablaIncidentes.fxml"));
        Parent StackPane = (Parent)cargaregistros.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(StackPane);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        registrosiniciales.setScene(scene);
        registrosiniciales.setTitle("Registro De Incidentes");
        registrosiniciales.show();

         registros.disableProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>(){
                @Override public void changed(ObservableValue ov,Boolean old_val, Boolean new_val){
                 registrosiniciales.show();

                  }

                  });
         registros.setDisable(true);
        }
```

the button is still disabled when i close the stage. any help or orientation?

Comment: Is your listener supposed to deal with this? Note that you listen to the `disabled` property of the button and show the `Stage`, when it changes, not "the other way round" (technically not 100% correct to say this here)... You simply call `show` twice for the stage here with the listener... Also what's the point in changing the gui, if it's not shown and therefore cannot be seen or interacted with?

Comment: @fabian I have a tableview as stage, what a i want, is once a show the tableview, disable the button that shows that tableview (stage) to prevent open this stage more that one time.

Comment: Consider using `stage.showAndWait()`. Much simpler than adding a listener to some property or listening to some events... (Doesn't work for the primary stage though.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
registrosiniciales.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
        {
          @Override
          public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> b, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue)
          {
            if(newValue == false) {
                registros.setDisable(true);
          }

          }
        });

        registrosiniciales.showingProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
        {
          @Override
          public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> b, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue)
          {
            if(newValue == false) {
                registros.setDisable(false);
          }

          }
        });
```

Comment: @fabian you mean this? the same windows still showing more that one time.